# Why won't is_search work inside functions.php?

Tags: search

I'm trying to use is_search to output some stuff from functions.php. I'm using is_search on the actual search page itself and it works fine:

```
if(is_search()) {
   echo get_search_query( '<h1>', '</h1>' );
}
```

But from functions.php this doesn't work:

```
function data_scroll_all(){
   if(is_search()) {
     $offset = $_POST['offset'];
     $category = $_POST['cat'];
     $args = array('posts_per_page' => 3, 'category__not_in' => 1, 'offset' => $offset, 'orderby' => 'date', 'cat' => $category);
     $loop = new WP_Query($args);
       if($loop->have_posts()) {
       while($loop->have_posts()){
       $loop->the_post(); 
       get_template_part( 'content-archive' );
       }
    } wp_reset_postdata();
 } else {
    echo "Nope!";
   }
die('');
```

}

With this I just get "Nope!" when I'm on the search page.

I have my search template setup like this:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Search Page
*/
?>
<?php
global $query_string;

$query_args = explode("&", $query_string);
$search_query = array();

foreach($query_args as $key => $string) {
    $query_split = explode("=", $string);
    $search_query[$query_split[0]] = urldecode($query_split[1]);
} // foreach

$search = new WP_Query($search_query);
?>
```

I have a a waypoint "infinite-scroll" function that triggers when reaching the bottom of the page:

```
var ajax_url = $('.loadAll').attr('data-url');
var cat = $('.loadAll').attr('data-cat');
var offset = -3;
$('#infinite-load').waypoint(function (direction) {
    if (direction === 'down') {
        offset = parseInt(offset) + 3;
        $.ajax({
            dataType: "HTML",
            url: ajax_url,
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                action: 'data_scroll_all',
                cat: cat,
                offset: offset
            },
            beforeSend: function () {
                $(".loading").show(); //show image loading
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $(".loading").hide();
                $('#infinite-load').append(data);
                $.waypoints('refresh');
            }
        });
    }
}, {
    offset: 'bottom-in-view'
});
```

Comment: How do you call `data_scroll_all()`? Oh, and read about [`parse_str()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php). ;)

Comment: `data_scroll_all` is not actually used anywhere in the code you posted.

Comment: @s_ha_dum well yea, the call works fine as it actually echos "nope" where it's supposed to, are you saying that it may be a problem because I'm making an ajax call which is not search.php?

Comment: If you call the function too early, it cannot work. This why we are asking for actual usage. Without that, an answer is impossible. It would also help if you’d intend your code for readability.

Comment: @toscho Ahh, I see, two ticks. Also, why did you mention `parse_str()`?

Comment: `parse_str()` would handle parsing the query string much more efficiently than your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ... the call works fine as it actually echos "nope" where it's supposed
>   to, are you saying that it may be a problem because I'm making an ajax
>   call which is not search.php?

An Ajax call is a *new* request to the server. The page that loads is (should be) `wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` which is template neutral. That ***is not*** a search page at all. `is_search` won't ever be `true`. What `is_search` does, in short, is check the main query to see if you are on a search results template page. With an AJAX call to `admin-ajax.php`, you aren't.

You could probably just remove that check as presumably your function is only used where appropriate, but you'd need to provide more context for a solid answer.

Comment: Great, that's exactly what I thought you meant when you inquired about the function. I need to check whether I am on the search page, I'm using a waypoint "infinite scroll" function that triggers "data_scroll_all" that trigger as you say is coming from `admin-aja.php`, so how else can I go about detecting what page I'm on so I can formulate an `if()` statement?

Comment: You can't detect what page you are on because you are on `admin-ajax.php`. If you need the function to operate based on the requesting "page" you will need to pass an argument through the request to `admin-ajax.php`

Comment: I just set a data attribute to 1 on the search page and just did a `if(isset())`. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't show where you call data_scroll_all() from, so this is just a blind guess -- apologies if it misses the mark.

It shouldn't matter which .php fike the function is in, but is_search() can only be called from within The Loop -- if the place your function is called from is outside the loop, it won't work.

(It's checking whether the current *query* is a search query, not whether or not you're on a search *page* )

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply :) you are correct, I've added some more code to my question.